# how to check which background image is displaying with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I basically want to use an if/else statement depending on which background image is displaying.

```
document.getElementById('background').style.background="url(assets/img/silhouette_5.jpg)"

if(document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundImage=="url(assets/img/silhouette_5.jpg)")
{
    alert("kek")
}else{
    alert(":(")
}
}
```

I've tried using both style.background and style.backgroundImage but couldn't make it work. No matter what I do,I get ":(" alert

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you setting your `background-image` using the (inline) `style` attribute, or with CSS (either in the `<head>` or in a stylesheet)? If the latter then you'd need to use `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('background'), null).backgroundImage`. Reference: [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: I set it with CSS on startup but upon section changes, I change it using style attribute. I'm guessing what I'm doing is wrong then

Comment: A better approach would be to have an identifier for each image and update a particular say 'imageId' attribute for the respective element displaying the image. You can then simply know which image is being displayed by getting it's 'imageId' attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just miss the `""` inside `url("...")`.

When you set the `url(...)` the code was generated to `url("...")`.

You can find it if you print background:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('background').style.background)
```

**Here is working code**

```js
document.getElementById('background').style.background="url(assets/img/silhouette_5.jpg)"

if(document.getElementById('background').style.background=='url("assets/img/silhouette_5.jpg")')
{
    alert("kek")
}else{
   alert(":(")
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help // daha fazla yardım için söyle

Comment: This answer is right. If you had done `console.log(document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundImage)`, you would see the result with quotes `url("assets/img/silhouette_5.jpg")`

Answer (score 0):

This works very well:

```
document.getElementById('background').setAttribute ("style","background: url(Images/background1.jpg)");
if(document.getElementById('background').getAttribute("style") == "background: url(Images/background1.jpg)") {
    alert("kek")
} else {
    alert(":(")
}

<div id="background"></div>
```